# Why is Apache Orc RecordReader.searchArgument() without success?

Tags: java

The predicates that were set at the time of the read were pushed down, but it doesn't seem to work from the print result, which is all printed out, which is not what I wanted

I refer to the following solutions, but there is no solution
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691416/why-is-apache-orc-recordreader-searchargument-not-filtering-correctly) why?

thank you!

```
public class parseOrcFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        try {
            String file_path = "/apps/hive/warehouse/orc_stu/test.orc";
            ReaderOptions readerOptions = OrcFile.readerOptions(conf);
            Path path = new Path(file_path);
            Reader reader = OrcFile.createReader(path, readerOptions);
            List<StripeInformation> sis = reader.getStripes();
            TypeDescription schema = reader.getSchema();
            SearchArgument sarg = SearchArgumentFactory.newBuilder()
                        .startNot()
                        .lessThan("id", PredicateLeaf.Type.LONG, 100L)
                        .end()
                        .startAnd()
                        .lessThan("id", PredicateLeaf.Type.LONG, 200L)
                        .end()
                        .build();

            Reader.Options opt = reader.options()
                        .schema(schema)
                        .include(new boolean[]{true, true, true, true, true})
                        .searchArgument(sarg, new String[]{null, "id", "name", "age", "sex"});

            RecordReader read_row_opt = reader.rows(opt);
            VectorizedRowBatch rowBatch = schema.createRowBatch();
            while (read_row_opt.nextBatch(rowBatch)) {
                System.out.println(rowBatch.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SearchArgument [filters](https://orc.apache.org/docs/indexes.html) only files, stripes, row groups. It doesn't filter rows with in a row group.