# C++ Apache Orc is not filtering data correctly

Tags: c++, orc

I am posting a simple c++ Apache orc file reading program which:

Read data from ORC file.

Filter data based on the given string.


 
Sample Code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>

// Orc specific headers.
#include <orc/Reader.hh>
#include <orc/ColumnPrinter.hh>
#include <orc/Exceptions.hh>
#include <orc/OrcFile.hh>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    orc::RowReaderOptions m_RowReaderOpts;
    orc::ReaderOptions m_ReaderOpts;

    std::unique_ptr<orc::Reader> m_Reader;
    std::unique_ptr<orc::RowReader> m_RowReader;

    auto builder = orc::SearchArgumentFactory::newBuilder();
    std::string required_symbol("FILTERME");

    /// THIS LINE SHOULD FILTER DATA BASED ON COLUMNS.
    /// INSTEAD OF FILTERING IT TRAVERSE EACH ROW OF ORC FILE.
    builder->equals("column_name", orc::PredicateDataType::STRING, orc::Literal(required_symbol.c_str(), required_symbol.size()));

    std::string file_path("/orc/file/path.orc");
    
    m_Reader = orc::createReader(orc::readFile(file_path.c_str()), m_ReaderOpts);
    m_RowReader = m_Reader->createRowReader(m_RowReaderOpts);
    m_RowReaderOpts.searchArgument(builder->build());
    
    auto batch = m_RowReader->createRowBatch(5000);

    try
    {
        
        std::cout << builder->build()->toString() << std::endl;
        while(m_RowReader->next(*batch))
        {
            const auto &struct_batch = dynamic_cast<const orc::StructVectorBatch&>(*batch.get());
            /** DO CALCULATIONS */
        }
        
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Total Time taken to read ORC file: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << " ms.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I tried searching on google for almost a week and tried to convert every possible java program into c++ to make my code works.

I tried to use the example in the [STACKOVERFLOW LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691416/why-is-apache-orc-recordreader-searchargument-not-filtering-correctly) which has a similar issue but didn't work for me.

**Question:**

 1. Am I wiring filtering code correctly. If yes then why it is not filtering data based on the given string.

 2. Where can I find the C++ or 'relevant Java code' for row-level or strip-level filter.

Comment: how does the metadata of your orc file looks like?

Comment: Try to call `orc::createReader` **AFTER** you have set `rowReaderOpts.searchArgument` value.

Comment: @Hitobat I tried changing the position of **rowReaderOpts.searchArgument** but it didn't work. Yesterday after doing some more Hit and trial actually resolve the issue. I'll post the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying multiple scenarios, I have resolved the above issue with ORC data filtering.
It was because of using the incorrect column number, I am not sure why there is a difference between the `column id` of the columns to fetch and columns to filter.
In above example I tried to filter data with `column name` and issue of filtering ORC with column name is still there. But unfortulately it is working fine with column number.

New Code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>

// Orc specific headers.
#include <orc/Reader.hh>
#include <orc/ColumnPrinter.hh>
#include <orc/Exceptions.hh>
#include <orc/OrcFile.hh>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    orc::RowReaderOptions m_RowReaderOpts;
    orc::ReaderOptions m_ReaderOpts;

    std::unique_ptr<orc::Reader> m_Reader;
    std::unique_ptr<orc::RowReader> m_RowReader;

    auto builder = orc::SearchArgumentFactory::newBuilder();
    std::string required_symbol("FILTERME");

    // <-- HERE COLUMN IDS ARE STARTING FROM 0-N. -->
    std::list<uint64_t> cols = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    m_RowReaderOpts.include(cols);

    int column_id = 7; // IN cols ABOVE, THIS COLUMN_ID 7 IS ACTUALLY 6. WHICH MEANS COLUMN_ID TO FILTER COLUMN IS +1 OF COLUMN ID PROVIDED IN DATA FETCH.
    builder->equals(column_id, orc::PredicateDataType::STRING, orc::Literal(required_symbol.c_str(), required_symbol.size()));

    std::string file_path("/orc/file/path.orc");
    
    m_Reader = orc::createReader(orc::readFile(file_path.c_str()), m_ReaderOpts);
    m_RowReader = m_Reader->createRowReader(m_RowReaderOpts);
    m_RowReaderOpts.searchArgument(builder->build());
    
    auto batch = m_RowReader->createRowBatch(5000);

    try
    {
        
        std::cout << builder->build()->toString() << std::endl;
        while(m_RowReader->next(*batch))
        {
            const auto &struct_batch = dynamic_cast<const orc::StructVectorBatch&>(*batch.get());
            /** DO CALCULATIONS */
        }
        
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Total Time taken to read ORC file: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << " ms.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

As per my understanding while resolving above issue is, column ids for fetching data starts from 0-N and for filtering it is 1-N. This is why you should provide `1`, when you require to filter data at column `0`.

Answer (score 0):

To explain the confusion in [the above answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70650632/5996453):

In ORC, column field id is a different thing than column type id:

- For files that have structs as the top-level object, field id 0 corresponds to the first struct field, field id 1 for the second struct field, and so on. See comments here: https://github.com/apache/orc/blob/v1.7.3/c++/include/orc/Reader.hh#L122-L123
- Column type id is the pre-order traversal index of the type tree. As mentioned in the [spec](https://orc.apache.org/specification/ORCv1/#type-information): The type tree is flattened in to a list via a pre-order traversal where each type is assigned the next id. Clearly the root of the type tree is always type id 0.

So if there are no nested types (struct/array/map) in the ORC file, we can see `columnTypeId == columnFieldId + 1` on all columns except the root struct type.

The ids used in building sargs are column type ids. However, the ids used in `RowReaderOptions::include(const std::list<uint64_t>& include)` are column field ids. To have a consistent id mapping, I'd recommend using the include method for type ids:
`RowReaderOptions::includeTypes(const std::list<uint64_t>& types);`